# Typescript issues with Redux and React latest versions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, package.json

I have been trying to upgrade to use the new create-react-app 2 and clean up all our files and versions at the same time so have installed the latest versions of React, Redux, etc in a new project.  I have been facing Typescript issues that seem to be based around Redux.

Before upgrade: you can see when I add the comma, it shows an action being dispatched to return an action
[image: Before: you can see when I add the comma, it shows an action being dispatched to return an action]

After upgrade: the same unchanged file, now it shows an action of type state being dispatched to return state!
[image: After: the same unchanged file, now it shows an action of type state being dispatched to return state!]

For clarity IAppAction is defined as follows:

```
import { Action } from 'redux';
export interface IAppAction extends Action {payload?: any}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this change has occurred and what should be done about it?

Versions I am currently trying:

```
 "react": "^16.6.0",
 "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
 "redux": "4.0.0",
 "react-redux": "5.0.7",
 "@types/react": "^16.4.18",
 "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
 "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
 "typescript": "3.0.3"
```

Have switched redux, react-redux and typescript in turn back to the prior versions shown here to try to solve the issues, with no success.

Comment: Well I worked out the explanation.  The earlier version we used of Dispatch<IAppState> was actually not the right type but it worked perfectly well with existing Redux libraries.  I had to switch to Dispatch<IAppAction> which makes sense since an action is what is being dispatched.  But first I tried various library combinations and the point it worked was the above versions but with "typescript": "3.1.6". I also had to change my bootstrap file to init(dispatch: Dispatch<IAppAction>) as well before it started working.